# How to Pass data from showmodalbottomsheet to Previous Page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

How i pass data from `showmodalbottomsheet` to previous page. Below is the sample code, what i have tried is there is a button when i click it displays modalbottomsheet and when i click on Done button it should pass `1` value to previous page and also i have added `setState` on `onTap` press but still it is not changing on previous page unless i click on `Flutter Hot Reload`. How to solve this issue?

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  String textResult = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(textResult),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      showModalBottomSheet(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0))),
                        context: context,
                        builder: (_) => StatefulBuilder(
                            builder: (BuildContext context, setState) {
                          return Container(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            textResult = "1";
                                          });
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                        },
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Done',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.red,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text('Press'))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, setState) {
```

with this line

```
builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setStateModal) {
```

**Explanation:**
The outer widget in the `build` (`Scaffold` and its content) and the widget inside the `showModalBottomSheet` have different `setState( )`. You have to make sure you call the outer one when you need to update parts of that widget. The idea is to `setState( )` of widgets outside your `showModalBottomSheet`. To be able to do that, you can give the two `setState()` different names so you know which one you are calling: `StateSetter setStateModal`

Comment: I tried but still not working
`builder: (_) => StatefulBuilder(builder:
                            (BuildContext context, StateSetter setStateModal)`
`onTap: () {
                                          setStateModal(() {
                                            textResult = "1";
                                          });
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                        },`

Comment: No, this is not what I told you to do. I said to change ONLY 1 line. You should not change the setState( ) in the bottom !!! it should refer to the outer widget. Try again. ONE LINE !!!

Comment: Unfair to not select this as "accepted" answer after I spend time debugging your code and provide the correct answer !

Answer (score 3):

@Canada2000's answer is ok. I'm just extending it.
The use `StatefulBuilder` inside `showDialog()` or `showModalBottomSheet()`+... is these widgets are separated from current context tree.

[image]

We use `StatefulBuilder` when we like to show changes on dialogs. `StatefulBuilder` has its own `state`⇾ `builder: (BuildContext context, setState)`  and calling `setState` is using `StatefulBuilder`'s setstate.

Now let's say you want to change both UI, to do that you need to simply rename `StatefulBuilder`'s state to something  like `SBsetState` inside builder as @Canada2000 said.

- to update the `_TestPageState` use `setState((){})`
- to update on dialog UI, use StatefulBuilder's state  like `SBsetState((){})`

You may can simple ignore StatefulBuilder if you don't want to show any changes on dialog.

**Your widget**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  String textResult = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("text Result ${textResult}"),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      showModalBottomSheet(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0))),
                        context: context,
                        builder: (_) => StatefulBuilder(
                            builder: (BuildContext context, setStateBTS) {
                          return Container(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            textResult = "1";
                                          });
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                        },
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Done',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.red,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text('Press'))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```